# 'volume' error using sound_play

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find a way a make sound_play work. I've been searching for days already, but I can't find a fix to this error. Have any of you ever experienced this error?

```
$ rosrun sound_play say.py 'Hello again'
```

> Saying: Hello again
> Voice: voice_kal_diphone Traceback (most recent call last):
> File: "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/sound_play/say.py",
> line 79, in 
> print 'Volume: %s' % volume NameError: name 'volume' is not
> defined

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225722/%27volume%27-error-using-sound_play/) by [the8Bitts](https://answers.ros.org/users/25831/the8bitts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug in sound_play. Please report it on the issue tracker.

**UPDATE**

The bug was reported here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues/72 and is fixed in the most recent release of sound_play, which has not yet made it to the public apt repository.

Until then, if this issue is a problem, please use audio_common from source by checking out the audio_common repository into your catkin workspace.

**DO NOT** modify the files in /opt/ros ; they are managed by the package manager and your changes may be overwritten at any time.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1